# Data fetched in ngOnInit does not display until I resize my browser

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have some data being fetched in an `ngOnInit()` for a dialog.  When the dialog initially pops up, there is no data displayed.  If I manually resize the browser window, it appears.  If I navigate to a different tab in the popup, then back to the original, the data also appears.
My ngOnInit -

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.route.params.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe( res => {
    this.itemId = res.itemId;
    this.getItemComponents(this.itemId);
    console.log(this.itemComponents);
}
```

The console.log shows undefined when the page loads.  I have put the same console.log in the getItemComponents method like so:-

```
getItemComponents {
  this.itemService.getComponents.subscribe( res => {
    this.itemComponents = res;
    console.log(this.itemComponents);
}
```

The console log above logs the data I want.
Any way around this?  I have tried using ngIf in my HTML and it doesn’t help.

Answer (score 0):

Your `console.log` method at `ngOnInit` hook launches earlier than your `getItemComponents` method subscription completes, so you need to combine it in one chain. Try to use something like:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params
        .pipe(
            takeUntil(this.destroy$),
            switchMap(res => this.itemService.getComponents(res.itemId))
        )
        .subscribe( data => {
            this.itemComponents = data;
            console.log(this.itemComponents);
        }
}
```